# Closed form for $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\cos(\pi \log n)}{n^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, logarithms, closed-form, trigonometric-series

Is there a closed form for the following sum? $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\cos(\pi\log n)}{n^2}$$

Comment: Do you know if there is a closed form (to which you want to know the answer) ? I personally don't think that there is one

Comment: @imranfat: No, I am not sure it is.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Of course there is. The fastest way to obtain it is to heuristically write $\cos(\pi\ln n)$ as $\frac12(n^{i\pi}+n^{-i\pi})$. The answer is then given by
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos\left(\pi\ln n\right)}{n^2}=\frac{\zeta(2+i\pi)+\zeta(2-i\pi)}{2}.$$

Comment: How do we simplify this, the answer has to be real of course

Comment: Well we can write this as $\mathrm{Re}\,\zeta(2+i\pi)$. One could also write something using integral representations of $\zeta(s)$. But I seriously doubt that one can get a more explicit evaluation.

Comment: I certainly don't disagree with your closed form answer (honestly, I wouldn't get that myself) but the point Zakharia and I were trying to make is that the answer has to be a real number, so your answer has imaginary terms in it, hence my question how to simplify it. Hoping that it would simplify to a number, say......5 (OK, kidding here)

Comment: I am completely satisfies with the answer. Thanks!

Comment: @Start wearing purple, We know that the series is convergent and you presented it by an special function (that is great). Now Would you tell me is it absolutely series or not?. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The numerical value  0.79564020673... has been added to https://oeis.org/A363687 .